# how to calculate the time taken to search for a word using binary search

Tags: c++, file, binary-search

```
int Binary_search()
{
    string word;
    cout << "Enter The Word You Want To Find : ";
    cin >> word;
    int start = 0, end = data.size() - 1;
    int mid, i = 0, counter = 0;
    while (start <= end)
    {
        mid = (end + start) / 2;
        if (data[i] == word)
            return i;

        else if (data[i] > word)
            end = mid - 1;

        else
            start = mid + 1;

        counter++;
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

if i wanna to know how much time this code would take to find a word in `data` which is a vector of type `string` and it loaded with words.

Comment: To measure, obtain clock times before and after, and subtract.    To calculate, more information would be needed (what target system - hardware, instruction set, speed of used instructions, memory, etc).   Whether calculating or measuring, the cases would need to be specified (e.g. how many words, what size words, etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) is the most accurate and hence it is used to measure execution time.

```
//Get the timepoint before the function is called
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
// Binary search ()
// Get ending timepoint..ie after you function is called
auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now(); 

// Get duration. Substart timepoints to  
// get durarion. To cast it to proper unit 
// use duration cast method 
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
```

Comment: can you explain it more

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: which library it belongs to ?

Comment: @Muhammadbakr It belongs to the c++ standard library (minimum standard compliance is c++11).

Comment: Unfortunately I am using c++98

Comment: can I find something similar to it in c++98

Comment: @Muhammadbakr "Unfortunately I am using c++98" - Then you should work to rectify that. Not seek solutions that will keep you stuck 20+ years in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) for that.

```
// get start time
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// do some work
Binary_search();

// get end time
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// calculate difference as double value in seconds
std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end-start;
// print the measured value
std::cout << "Time taken : " << diff.count() << " seconds\n";
```